# How to upload the csv into my folder in s3 bucket?

Tags: python, sql, csv, amazon-s3

My requirement is I want to upload the csv file from localhost to my folder in s3 bucket but I don't have any idea of how to give the folder name in the below code.
Can somebody help me with this?

```
import boto3
import os

def upload_files(path):
    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id='',
        aws_secret_access_key='',
        region_name='us-east-1'
    )
    s3 = session.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket('ag-tpch')

    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            full_path = os.path.join(subdir, file)
            with open(full_path, 'rb') as data:
                bucket.put_object(Key=full_path[len(path)+1:], Body=data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    upload_files('E:/expenses/shape')
```

Comment: "i don't have any idea of how to give the foldername in the below code" What code?

Comment: please see the code which i posted and help me clear this @tagc

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are trying to upload all the files under "E:/expenses/shape" to S3.

I have changed it to single file, you could later modify it according to your requirement.

```
import boto3
import os

def upload_file(path):
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id='',
    aws_secret_access_key='',
    region_name='us-east-1'
)
s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('ag-tpch')

with open(path, 'rb') as data:
            bucket.put_object(Key='some/path/to-s3/test1.csv'], Body=data)
//your s3 path will be /some/path/to-s3/test-x.csv
if __name__ == "__main__":
upload_files('E:/expenses/shape/test1.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you so much but my question is how to upload the file into my folder in s3 bucket

Comment: change this bucket.put_object(Key='some/path/to-s3/test1.csv'] to bucket.put_object(Key='my-folder/test1.csv']

Comment: If i need any help , i will reach you

Comment: yes this is simple and easy way to upload the file in required folder in s3 bucket. It's working perfectly

Comment: I want to reach you whenever i get doubts in python code. Is there any way to follow you sir?